# По заданным координатам вершин треугольника вычислить длины его медиан

Tags: python

Есть код, но он не проходит такой тест:

- x1=3
- y1=0
- x2=0
- y2=4
- x3=0
- y3=0
- m1= 3.605551275463989 (должно быть 4.27)
- m2= 4.0 (должно 2.5)
- m3= 4.272001872658765 (только это верно)

Вроде нужно В функцию
med передать не четыре переменных, а шесть. Добавить x3, y3.
В вызова функции тоже должно быть шесть переменных. Но сделать толково не получается

```py
def med(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    import math
    med=math.sqrt((x1-(x2+x3)/2)**2+(y1-(y2+y3)/2)**2)
    return med

x1=float(int(input("x1=" )))
y1=float(int(input("y1=" )))
x2=float(int(input("x2=" )))
y2=float(int(input("y2=" )))
x3=float(int(input("x3=" )))
y3=float(int(input("y3=" )))

print("m1=",med(x1, y1, x2, y2))
print("m2=",med(x2, y2, x3, y3))
print("m3=",med(x2, y2, x1, y1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в чем проблема то?

В Википедии даётся формула

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше ее всего лишь надо реализовать:

```
def med(p1, p2, p3):
    a = (p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2
    b = (p3[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p3[1] - p2[1])**2
    c = (p3[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p3[1] - p1[1])**2

    return math.sqrt(2*a + 2*b - c) / 2
```

и вызывать

```
med((x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3))
```

по хорошему предварительно надо проверить, что точки вообще образуют треугольник, но это вопрос уже из другой серии

Comment: Зачем считать медиану через длины сторон, когда есть координаты вершин? И да, три точки всегда образуют треугольник (иногда вырожденный, но медианам это не помеха).